# Triple Integral to Find Volume

Tags: calculus

Question: Use a triple integral to find the volume of the solid enclosed by the parabaloids $y=x^2+z^2$ and $y=8-x^2-z^2$.

My attempt: The best I can figure, this object looks kind of like a football oriented along the $y$-axis from $y=0$ to $y=8$ and is symmetric about the $y$-axis and the plane $y=4$.

It seems best to integrate first with respect to $y$, and $x^2+z^2 \le y \le 8-(x^2+z^2)$.

The widest part of the football is at $y=4$; substitute that into both of the equations above to find that the projection onto the $xz$-plane is $x^2+z^2=4$, or a circle of radius 2, so my bounds for $z$ are $-\sqrt{4-x^2} \le z \le \sqrt{4-x^2}$ and my bounds for $x$ are $-2 \le x \le 2$.

But I believe I can make this easier by integrating from $0\le z \le \sqrt{4-x^2}$ and multiplying by 2 and integrating from $0 \le x \le 2$ and multiplying by another 2. (I actually think I can integrate $y$ from $4 \le y \le 8-(x^2+z^2)$ and multiply by another 2, but that doesn't seem to simplify anything.)

Since I'm finding the volume, the function I integrate is one. I come up with this
$$4\int_0^2 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} \int_{x^2+z^2}^{8-(x^2+z^2)} 1\ dy\ dz\ dx.$$
(Is this right so far?)

If nothing's wrong yet, I still can't finish this integral
$$4\int_0^2 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} \int_{x^2+z^2}^{8-\left(x^2+z^2\right)} 1\ dy\ dz\ dx \\ 
4\int_0^2 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} y \Big|_{x^2+z^2}^{8-\left(x^2+z^2\right)} dz\ dx \\ 
4\int_0^2 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} \left(8-\left(x^2+z^2\right)\right)-\left(x^2+z^2\right) dz\ dx \\ 
4\int_0^2 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} \left(8-2x^2-2z^2\right)\ dz\ dx \\ 
4\int_0^2 \left[\left(8-2x^2\right)z-\frac 23 z^3\right]_0^{\sqrt{4-x^2}} \ dx \\
4\int_0^2 \left[ \left(8-2x^2\right)\sqrt{4-x^2} - \frac 23 \sqrt{4-x^2}^3 \right]\ dx \\
-\frac{16}3\int_0^2 \left[ \left(x^2 -4\right)\sqrt{4-x^2} \right]\ dx \\
\vdots \\ ??$$

Comment: Check the volume that they are asking for, it isn't the volume of the solid enclosed by the two paraboloid. It's the volume of the tetrahedron enclosed by those two paraboloids.

Comment: @D.A.Robayo I put the wrong word when I copied the question. I fixed the post. They want the volume of the solid enclosed by the parabaloids. My bad.

Comment: Note: Mathematica and Maple say the answer is $16 \pi$. But I still want to know how to do the integral.

Comment: Corrected it, what exactly you don't understand?

Comment: Note: D.A.Robayo's answer probably most advanced answer, but Mike's was the most basic and didn't use skills that haven't been reached in the textbook yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral in your last line can be simplified to 
$$
\frac{16}3\int_0^2 (4-x^2)^{3/2}\,dx
$$
To do this, first use the substitution $x=2\sin\theta$, obtaining
$$
\frac{16}3\int_0^{\pi/2}(4-4\sin^2\theta)^{3/2}\cos\theta\,d\theta=
8\cdot\frac{16}3\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^4\theta\,d\theta
$$
To complete the integral, use the identity $\cos^2\phi = \frac{1+\cos(2\phi)}2$ to write
$$
\cos^4\theta = \left(\frac{1+\cos(2\theta)}{2}\right)^2=\frac12+\cos(2\theta)+\frac14\cos^22\theta=\frac12+\cos(2\theta)+\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1+\cos(4\theta)}{2}\right)
$$

Answer (score 2):

The volume will be represented by the triple integral:

$\int \int \int _{\Omega} dV = \Gamma$ where $ \Omega$ is the solid enclosed by the two paraboloids. The paraboloids intersect in $y = 4$ So:

$\Gamma = \int \int_{\Omega'} \int_{x^{2}+z^{2}}^{8-(x^{2}+z^{2})}dV$. Where $\Omega'= $$\{(x,z) \lvert  x^{2} + z^{2} \leq 4 \}$.

So:
$\Gamma = \int \int_{\Omega´}8-2(x^{2}+z^{2})dA$

Using the substitution:
$x = r cos(\theta)$ and $z = r sin(\theta)$, $0 \leq r \leq 2$ and $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.
$\Gamma = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2}r(8-2r^{2})drd\theta$

So $\Gamma = 2\pi(4(2^2) - (2)^3) = 16\pi$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:For a start, it is convenient to put $ x^2+z^2 = r^2$, so that you have solids of revolution:

$$ y_1=r^2 ,\ y_2=8-r^2 $$.

Comment: We haven't reached the cylindrical part of the text yet.

Comment: Just keep in mind the Jacobian and you'll be fine.